# "Blurt to" vs "blurt at."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

What the correct option, or maybe both are correct?

I'm confused because I got more or less the same number of Google Book results for each of them:

[he blurted at her.](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=DWKWW-G2Hc_N-Qbe35XACg&q=%22he%20blurted%20at%20her%22&oq=%22he%20blurted%20at%20her%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2997.6371.0.6550.10.8.1.0.0.0.87.403.8.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0._-GE3QDn_8Q)

[he blurted to her.](https://www.google.com.tw/search?biw=1855&bih=990&tbm=bks&ei=FmKWW8nwNYvs-Qb50Ku4DQ&q=%22he%20blurted%20to%20her%22&oq=%22he%20blurted%20to%20her%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...53263.54043.0.54241.2.2.0.0.0.0.32.61.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.IsEq3x9mAHs)

Comment: "The same number" is effectively almost nothing (5 vs 8) which should make you wonder if either of the two options is even idiomatic. In comparison, "he blurted out" gets some 222000 (!) results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To blurt** in contemporary usage is to reveal a fact or to say something *acting on impulse*. The speaker is speaking impetuously, not carefully considering the implications of his or her words, is not choosing words carefully, and is not speaking in what might be called a measured manner.

Grammatically it works like the verb **spit**.

We can spit.

We can spit something.

We can spit something out.

We can spit at someone.

We can spit something at someone.

We can even spit to someone and spit something to someone.

You can substitute **blurt** for **spit** in those sentences.

When we **blurt** something **to** someone, they are merely  the listener.  When we blurt something **at** someone, there is usually some animus on the part of the speaker.

> "Are you blind!?" the athlete blurted at the referee.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the expressions seems common - COCA does not seem to contain citations for either, and your Google Books results quote only 8 books between the two phrases.

If I had to guess, the difference between the phrases would probably be similar to the difference between *yell at* and *yell to* - the use of *at* implies that the blurted out remark is meant to somehow belittle the addressee, while *to* just means that it was directed to them.

Note that [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+blurt+at) provides the following definition for **blurt at**:

> to speak contemptuously of.

quoting Shakespeare's *Pericles*, but it seems like the usage in your citations does not match this definition.